# Why doesn't `yarn outdated` show babel 7 as latest?

Tags: babeljs, yarnpkg, package-managers

I currently have babel v6 installed, and `yarn outdated` does not show anything about babel v7. (I have the latest version of yarn, 1.15.2)

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
```

I'm just wondering why that is, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From v6 to v7, babel changed their package naming convention from `babel` to `@babel`. To get the newest version of babel, you need to use the entirely new packages.